# Select nth element (among elements with same class name) and style :after pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 5 elements with the classname `picked`. each element has a div with classname `title`. i added `:after` pseudo element for each `.title` and need to set different background for each pseudo element.

it would be best if it could be done in **pure** CSS, but i couldn't find anything and maybe it needs javascript.

```css
.picked {
display: inline-block;
}
.picked .title:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div>
```

ps. i have set `background: #000;` so that they are visible in the preview.

tnx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.picked {
  display: inline-block;
}

.picked .title:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}
.picked:nth-of-type(1) .title:after {
  background: red;
}

.picked:nth-of-type(2) .title:after {
  background: yellow;
}
.picked:nth-of-type(3) .title:after {
  background: green;
}
.picked:nth-of-type(4) .title:after {
  background: pink;
}
.picked:nth-of-type(5) .title:after {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at `:nth-of-type(n)`?

```css
.picked {
  display: inline-block;
}

.picked .title:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}

.picked:nth-of-type(2) .title:after {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included an example for the second child.

```css
.picked {
  display: inline-block;
}

.picked .title:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}

.picked:nth-child(2) .title:after {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
<div class="picked">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.picked {
display: inline-block;
}
.picked .title:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.picked:nth-child(1) .title:after {background: red}
.picked:nth-child(2) .title:after {background: green}
.picked:nth-child(3) .title:after {background: blue}
.picked:nth-child(4) .title:after {background: yellow}
.picked:nth-child(5) .title:after {background: orange}
```

```html
<div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div><div class="picked"><div class="title"></div></div>
```